# Event occured when phone receives call Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing an Windows Phone Application and I wanted to know that when some page is showing on the screen and the phone receives a call, which event occurs? How do I subscribe to that event?

In Windows phone 8 it was Obscured event.

Is there any similar event??

Comment: Doesn't the app still get suspended? If so is subscribing to the suspended event okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd watch [CoreWindow.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.activated.aspx)Activated to see when the app's window is activated and deactivated.

```
{
   ...
   Window.Current.Activated += Current_Activated;
   ...
}

void Current_Activated(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Activated {0}", e.WindowActivationState));
}
```